# About getting a friendship network through the new Twitter api

Tags: twitter

Do you know whether it is possible to retrieve the "friendship" network in a group of Twitter users (where @X is considered to be friend of @Y when @X follows @Y) through the new Twitter api?

In other words, given two arbitrary Twitter users, do you know whether Twitter api replies to queries whether one of them follows the other one or not, when this query is made by some third party (using different authorization credentials from the ones of the former two users)?

If yes, how's is it done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Twitter REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public)

> The REST APIs provide programmatic access to read and write Twitter data. Author a new Tweet, read author profile and follower data, and more. The REST API identifies Twitter applications and users using OAuth; responses are available in JSON.

Specifically, you will need to use these two calls:

1. GET friends

> Returns a cursored collection of user IDs for every user the specified user is following (otherwise known as their “friends”).

2. GET followers

> Returns a cursored collection of user IDs for every user following the specified user.

There is not such a query *exactly* as you want, with input arguments @X and @Y, but with these two you should be fine.